# Behance API not let me create API key

Tags: behance-api

Behance isn't giving me the option to create an API key at all. I've tried logging in from a free and paid account.
The manage apps section isn't giving me the option to create an app either.

**Screenshot of [behance.net/dev/apps](http://behance.net/dev/apps)**

[image]

I'm super confused. How do I register an app on Behance so I can get an API key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got some feedback from Behance Help Center. Hope it's helpful for you!﻿

> The public Behance API is no longer accepting new clients.
>
> If you are a current API user you will still be able to edit and
> access the content returned by the API. Anything you have already
> built that uses the API will continue to function as it always has and
> our developer documentation can still be found by navigating to
> https://www.behance.net/dev.